# В чем особенность применения блока transaction (AR)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Учился по этому мануалу: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Да и по текущий момент пишу создание, обновление или удаление по тому же принципу.

Недавно наткнулся на странный (для меня) код. Все интересное по сути происходит в методах create, update и destroy. И вот в теле этих методов весь банальный (save/create, update_attributes и т. д.) код обернут в такие блоки:

```
Post.transaction(isolation: :serializable) do
    # Тут сохраняем, обновляем или удалаяем.
end
```

В чем их преимущество на фоне простого?

```
def create
    # Код специально обрезан для ясности
    post = Post.new(post_params)
    post.save!
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это исполнение кода в транзакции с явно указанным уровнем изоляции. Бывает полезно, когда код приложения вносит изменения, зависящие от того, что было прочитано.

`SERIALIZABLE` в РСУБД является самым строгим. Он гарантирует, что результат будет таким же, как если бы транзакции применялись последовательно, в один поток (и применение в один поток можно считать наивной реализацией такой изоляции).

Реализовываться это может по-разному, в зависимости от РСУБД, смотрите документацию к тому, что используете.

- MySQL блокирует затрагиваемые данные и диапазоны значений на запись. Те, кому запись нужна, ждут.
- PostgreSQL следит за тем, какие данные затрагивают параллельно работающие транзакции. Если обнаруживается пересечение, к сохранению допускается только одна из пересекшихся транзакций, а другие обламываются с ошибкой "serialization failure". Приложение может отреагировать на это повторным запуском своего кода от начала транзакции.
- MSSQL поддерживает оба способа, но `SERIALIZABLE` заставляет ждать тех, кому нужна запись в затрагиваемые данные. А режим облома конфликтующих транзакций с ошибкой называется иначе, `SNAPSHOT`. Эффект изоляции одинаков, но приложения "чувствуют" его по-разному.

При более слабой изоляции:

- одинаковые последовательные чтения могут давать не актуальные *на текущий момент* результаты, а актуальные на момент старта транзакции, в `REPEATABLE READ`
- одинаковые последовательные чтения в транзакции могут давать разные результаты, если между ними была применена другая транзакция, в `READ COMMITTED`

Могут быть и более тонкие нюансы. Читайте документацию к вашей РСУБД.